Why am I receiving syntax error for php code for opayo PI integrating?
This is my code:
if (Secure3Dv2Notification::isRequest($_POST)) {
    
    $secure3Dv2Notification = new Secure3Dv2Notification::fromData($_POST);
    
    // If you need the sent session data, it can be found here:

    $encThreeDSSessionData = $secure3Dv2Notification->getThreeDSSessionData();
    $threeDSSessionData = base64_decode($encThreeDSSessionData);
    
    
    $request = new CreateSecure3Dv2Challenge(
        $endpoint, $auth, $notification, $transactionId
    );

    $response = $client->sendRequest($request);
    $transaction = ResponseFactory::fromHttpResponse($response);
    
    
}

I am receiving this error:

Syntax error, unexpected T-STRING, expecting T_VARIABLE

It is this line:
$secure3Dv2Notification = new Secure3Dv2Notification::fromData($_POST);

What is wrong with it?

new Secure3Dv2Notification::fromData($_POST) is invalid. You can't use the new keyword while also calling a class function.

If fromData method is static method you should use like this
 $secure3Dv2Notification = Secure3Dv2Notification::fromData($_POST);

If fromData is non-static method you should use
 $secure3Dv2Notification = (new Secure3Dv2Notification())->fromData($_POST);

